# Customização response 403 Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Fala galera!

Segue a minha situação:

Tenho uma aplicação com autenticação JWT. A autenticação é feita na base de dados e eu preciso adicionar agora mais 2 validações: contagem insucesso no login e dispositivo cadastrado. Para fazer isso, criei uma classe **CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider** exetendendo do **DaoAuthenticationProvider** (esse segundo fornecido no Spring).

Dentro dessa classe, sobrecrevi o método **additionalAuthenticationChecks** e escrevi as devidas validações, cada uma lançando um exceção diferente (LockedException e BadCredentialsException - ambas filhas de AuthenticationException)

O que eu preciso:

O retorno do request vir com a respectiva mensagem de validação.

O que está ocorrendo:

Em caso de insucesso, o retorno vem sempre o seguinte:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1548779620976,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/app/api/v1.1/login"
}
```

O que já tentei fazer para resolver o caso:

- No JWTLoginFilter sobrescrevi o método unSuccessfulAuthentication e fiz um response.sendError(). Resultado: o método até é chamado, mas a mensagem padrão continua retornando.
- No JWAuthenticationFilter coloquei um bloco de try/catch em volta da chamada do autenticate visando capturar e lançar a exceção, mas isso não ocorre visto que, aparentemente, o tratamento da exceção ocorre antes.
- Criei um CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint seguindo o sugerido em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306302/spring-security-creating-403-access-denied-custom-response. A mensagem atá mudou, mas alguma outra exceção se sobrepôs à minha e o retorno foi:

  {
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "timestamp": 1548780759071,
    "status": 403
  }

Nesse último caso setei no value do message a mensagem presenta na minha exceção.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver esse caso? Desde já agradeço a atenção de vocês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia criar um handler e tratar uma exceção específica sua para estas ocasiões, por exemplo:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {UserServiceException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserServiceException(UserServiceException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorMessage(new Date(), ex.getMessage()), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorMessage(new Date(), ex.getMessage()), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

No meu caso estou retornando a seguinte entidade:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErrorMessage {

    private Date timestamp;
    private String message;

}
```

Quando eu lanço uma `UserServiceException`, recebo o seguinte retorno:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-07T14:17:55.639+0000",
    "message": "Record with provided id is not found"
}
```

Claro que você precisa de outras informações no retorno, mas você pode complementar sua `ErrorMessage` de acordo, da mesma forma como você pode criar uma nova exceção relacionada ao seu fluxo de autenticação e tratar no handler.